# How to make all new files in the directory be owned by the particular user?

Tags: linux, permissions

I want all the files in `/var/www` directory be owned by nginx.devel. 
I have performed `chmod` once and update these files using `rsync`.

But if I create a new file and then `rsync` it, it will be owned by user.user and I need to run `chmod` with `sudo` privileges on it.

Comment: user is not nginx?

Comment: yes. It is different user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.  Well, not automatically anyway.  You *can*, however, enforce group permissions, which with careful planning and an appropriate umask, can solve most permissions problems.  If you set the setgid bit on the `/var/www` directory it will ensure that any new files created under it are owned by the `devel` group.

Note that depending on which flags you use, `rsync` may override this behavior and replicate the ownership of the source files.

To set the setgid bit:

```
$ ls -ld test
drwxr-xr-x 2 insyte insyte 4096 2009-08-13 04:39 test
$ chmod g+s test
$ ls -ld test
drwxr-sr-x 2 insyte insyte 4096 2009-08-13 04:39 test
```

Demo of the behavior:

```
$ id
uid=1000(insyte) gid=1000(insyte) groups=4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom)
$ ls -ld test
drwxr-xr-x 2 insyte backup 4096 2009-08-13 04:39 test
$ touch test/file1
$ ls -l test
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 insyte insyte 0 2009-08-13 04:43 file1
$ sudo chmod g+s test
$ ls -ld test
drwxr-sr-x 2 insyte backup 4096 2009-08-13 04:43 test
$ touch test/file2
$ ls -l test
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 insyte insyte 0 2009-08-13 04:43 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 insyte backup 0 2009-08-13 04:44 file2
```

The effect is recursive as well; any new directories created after you set the setgid bit will also have the setgid bit set.

An alternative to this approach, of course, would be a cron job that runs every minute and fixes the permissions on the files under `/var/www/`.